# The Wider Empire and the wrong parts of Britain

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following quotation is taken from an article by Fintan O'Toole titled *This glorious and unruly English that lets everyone in.* (The Observer, Sunday 15 September 2013)

What do the terms "the wider empire" and "the wrong parts of Britain" refer to respectively?  I suppose that Canada, Australia, New Zealand and India are included in the former, and former British colonies in Africa are included in the latter.  Am I right?

> Writers from the wider empire, as well as from the "wrong" parts of Britain, could have written the same (as James Joyce did).

Comment: Bahrain vs Britain.

Comment: I suspect _wrong parts of Britain_ refers to regions of England with lower-class dialects.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that *wrong* is written in quotation marks is the clue to interpretation.

The *"wrong" part of Britain* is Ireland.

What is now the Republic of Ireland has never been part of the Empire but was considered part of the Kingdom for many years.  Ireland was often referred to as part of Britain - which of course it is not.

The author is harking back to this time and to the works of James Joyce, a great Irish writer of the early 20th Century.  Some of his works were banned in England, hence the tongue-in-cheek reference to the wrong part of Britain.